# How to enable adbd to listen to a port at boot time in Android?

Tags: adb, connection-issues, reboot, boot

I have a rooted HTC Hero, and what I want to do is to enable the adbd
to listen to a port at boot time.

I tried some code found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=635102):

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

in an Android shell and it works great.

I tried to change the **init.rc** file. I added the above code in init.rc
and I replaced it with the original file, through these commands:

```
adb push init.rc sdcard

adb shell
adb su
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /
adb cp sdcard/init.rc /
```

The file is replaced successfully, but when I reboot my phone and try to connect
through:

```
adb connect <IP>:5555
```

the connection is not being established.

Any ideas?

(PS. I don't want to use the [remoteADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jaja.remoteadb&hl=en) application and a shell command like
    `am start -n ...`
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it does not work properly is this:

The `init.rc` script resides in within the RAMDisk attached to the boot image.

Hence the `init.rc` script that was edited and pushed across is now overwritten by the boot image's own script upon reboot - effectively changes are lost!

You need to extract the boot image, using every boot image has the kernel and the RAMDisk. The tools available to do this can be found [here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images).

## Extracting

When invoking the script `split_bootimg.pl` on a boot image it will recreate the following:

- boot.kernel
- boot.ramdisk.gz

The two files are obviously self-explanatory. To extract the ramdisk, create a directory called ***RAMDisk*** and from that directory, invoke this: `gzip -dc | cpio -i`, to recreate the directory structure that is used in the RAMDisk which gets flipped over to the live file-system upon boot. In there, the file that is of pertinent information is `init.rc`. Now that can be modified to your heart's content.

## Putting it back together

Go back up a directory level, and issue this - `mkbootfs ***RAMDisk*** | gzip > my_custom_ramdisk.gz`.

Then, to "attach" the original kernel to the boot image, issue the following: `mkbootimg -base 0x.... -kernel boot.kernel -ramdisk my_custom_ramdisk.gz -o my_custom_boot.img`.

At this point now, a boot image has been constructed, then that boot image will now have to be flashed via `fastboot flash boot my_custom_boot.img`.

## TL;DR

Changes are lost upon re-boot because the script is not properly edited which required extracting the boot image and modifying it and re-packing it. Once re-packed and then the boot image is re-flashed, the changes will be permanent.

This is done every-time the changes are needed.

Answer (score 4):

Replace "service" by "persist" to keep it upon reboot :

```
    setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555
```

Comment: worked for me on Vibe UI 2.0, Android 4.4.2

Comment: It also works in Android 7.1.1. Thx